# Detect bluetooth headset button press

Tags: macos, cocoa

I've searched in google but i didnt get what i want.

Is there a way to detect headset button press?

I'm using speech recogniser to take inputs from user and it works fine. It works continuously and waits for a specific word to activate but I thought of using a bluetooth/any headphones with remote control to activate it by pressing a specific button instead.

I came across answers where they said that it is possible for media apps only to play/pause/volume control.